# Logo not showing on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I wanna know why the logo is not showing on mobile devices, I tried resetting my network on phone, and reset web browser.I also try making the logo little smaller from 100px to 80px but still it's not showing. Here is the code below. Please Help Thanks is advance. Here is the working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/light22/60xrbkhf/#&togetherjs=fHfHVyawIa

```
<header id="header" class="transparent-header" data-sticky-class="not-dark">

            <div id="header-wrap" style="height:180px;">

                <!-- Primary Navigation "
                ============================================= -->
                <nav id="primary-menu" class="style-2 center">

                    <!--<div class="container clearfix"></div>-->
                        <div id="primary-menu-trigger"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>
                        <div style="text-align:center">
                        <ul class="one-page-menu" data-easing="easeInOutExpo" data-speed="1250" data-offset="65" >
                            <li><a href="index.html"><div style="border-bottom:1px solid #000">Home</div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html"><div>WHO WE ARE</div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="products.html"><div>WHAT WE TRADE</div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="services.html"><div>SERVICES</div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="logistic.html"><div>LOGISTICS</div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html"><div>CONTACT</div></a></li>  
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                </nav><!-- #primary-menu end -->
                <!-- Logo
                ============================================= -->

                <div id="logo" class="divcenter">
                    <a href="index.html" class="standard-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo-dark.png"><img class="divcenter" src="images/logo.png" alt="Canvas Logo"></a>
                    <a href="index.html" class="retina-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo-dark@2x.png"><img class="divcenter" src="images/logo@2x.png" alt="Canvas Logo"></a>
                </div><!-- #logo end -->
                <br>
            </div>

        </header><!-- #header end -->
```

Comment: how to identify where is problem. give working example like js fiddle

Comment: @LaljiTadhani https://jsfiddle.net/light22/60xrbkhf/#&togetherjs=fHfHVyawIa

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your style sheet for that section?

Comment: Check in Media Query CSS, You Might have Givens Some Special Class

Comment: not found this image "images/logo@2x.png"

Comment: file name incorrect you file name is "1logo@2x.png"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename image in your images folder

```
1logo@2x.png to logo@2x.png
```